# aws lambda function access restrcition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am new in aws I want to restrict my aws lambda function to not get access by any other resource it can only invoke by a specified lambda function.
I have not setup an API gateway for this lambda function it's just a simple lambda function that I want to invoke from another lambda function but also want to restrict to not getting invoked by other resources or another lambda function so I want to specify another lambda function which will invoke this lambda function so only specified lambda function can invoke

Answer (score 2):

You can modify/delete [resource-based policies for Lambda - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html).

Normally, these policies define which IAM users, IAM roles and AWS services can invoke the function. You should edit the policies attached to this particular Lambda function to only permit access via your desired 'calling' Lambda function. This will *probably* involve referencing the IAM Role that is used by the 'calling' Lambda function.

You could even add a `Deny` policy to prohibit access via any other IAM Role or service.